# zombienet: Err: Can not create the forwarding to the tracing collator

Tags: zombienet

Regarding Substrate's Zombienet https://github.com/paritytech/zombienet

I setup a folder with the following file structure:

- zombienet-linux ... this is downloaded from the Zombienet repo release page, then made into executable
- 001-small-network.toml ... this is copied from https://github.com/paritytech/zombienet#configuration-files-and-examples -> A minimal configuration example with two validators and one parachain:

  [settings]
  timeout = 1000

  [relaychain]
  default_image = "paritypr/polkadot-debug:master"
  chain = "rococo-local"

  ```
  [[relaychain.nodes]]
  name = "alice"

  [[relaychain.nodes]]
  name = "bob"
  ```

  [[parachains]]
  id = 100

  ```
  [parachains.collator]
  name = "collator01"
  image = "paritypr/colander:4131-ccd09bbf"
  command = "adder-collator"
  ```

Then I ran it according to their Github repo readme:

```
minikube start
./zombienet-linux spawn ./001-small-network.toml
```

Then I received a error message along with other terminal output: `Err: Can not create the forwarding to the tracing collator`

```
launching collator01 pod with image paritypr/colander:4131-ccd09bbf
     with command: /cfg/zombie-wrapper.sh adder-collator --chain /cfg/rococo-local.json --name collator01 --rpc-cors all --unsafe-rpc-external --rpc-methods unsafe --unsafe-ws-external --no-mdns --node-key 5e123980fad4770d9ab5b7df7bbee8499943822a8555d11995e8203210065342 --no-telemetry --bootnodes /ip4/172.17.0.7/tcp/30333/ws/p2p/12D3KooWQCkBm1BYtkHpocxCwMgR8yjitEeHGx8spzcDLGt2gkBm --listen-addr /ip4/0.0.0.0/tcp/30333/ws --base-path /data
    collator01 pod is ready!
collator01 running

     You can follow the logs of the node by running this command: 

         kubectl logs -f collator01
```

child process exited

```
 Err: Can not create the forwarding to the tracing collator
```

---

```
 Network launched 

     In namespace zombie-d24c33d968bc53980b678efe8f82f35c with kubernetes provider


     Node name: alice

     Node direct link: https://polkadot.js.org/apps/?rpc=ws%3A%2F%2F127.0.0.1%3A33239#/explorer

     Node prometheus link: http://127.0.0.1:38401/metrics
```

---

```
     Node name: bob

     Node direct link: https://polkadot.js.org/apps/?rpc=ws%3A%2F%2F127.0.0.1%3A35105#/explorer

     Node prometheus link: http://127.0.0.1:44355/metrics
```

---

```
 Parachain ID: 100


     Node name: collator01

     Node direct link: https://polkadot.js.org/apps/?rpc=ws%3A%2F%2F127.0.0.1%3A35531#/explorer

     Node prometheus link: http://127.0.0.1:33107/metrics
```

---

Is that error normal or How can I solve that error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://github.com/paritytech/zombienet/issues/178
This is a bug since ZombieNet is trying to get the forwarding-port for the tracing collector service without validate if the service is available.
but this shouldn't cause issues to both spawn or test networks.

fixed in newer releases

Comment: Thanks, this is fixed in v1.2.31.